$L|K$ is an algebraic extension. If $L$ is perfect then $K$ is perfect counter example.
I'm want to se where this fails.
I know for finite extension $L|K$ , $K$ perfect iff $L$ is perfect, as discus here. If $L\mid K$ is a finite extension of fields then K is perfect iff L is perfect
I prove here for an algebraic extension $L|K$ if $K$ is perfect then $L$ is perfect. $L|K$ is an algebraic extrension. If $K$ is perfect then $L$ is perfect.
If I try to prove it, we take $L|K$ algebraic, and $L$ perfect.
For $f \in K[x]$ irreducible we have that $f \in L[x]$ is irreducible, we are done. In other case, I understand that $f=f_1\cdots f_n$ are the irreducible factos of $f$ in $L[x]$ so the problem is that could be for some $i \neq j$ that $x -\alpha$ divides both $f_i$ and $_j$, so as I understand that from the point of view of $f \in K[x]$, $f$ has multiple roots from the same irreducible polynomial (itself).
First, are ok my thougts?
Second, there is a explicit example of this situacion, in the one it fails?

Algebraically closed fields are perfect. So take your favorite non-perfect field $K$ and let $L$ be an algebraic closure of $K$, and you've got a counterexample.
